# Angular Form Required doesn't work

Tags: forms, angular

I put a simple form input in my form but required doesn't work for me and from with empty input submitted. 
Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="test" 
        required
        name="test">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my form tag:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

Here is my submit button tag:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add ngNativeValidate in your form tag:

```
<form ngNativeValidate class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```